# Java Handling Colors With Pixels How Works

Tags: java, colors

```
private int[] colors = new int[6 * 6 * 6];
```

...

```
int index = 0;
for(int r = 0 ; r < 6 ; r++){
    for(int g = 0 ; g < 6 ; g++){
        for(int b = 0 ; b < 6 ; b++){
            int rr = r * 255 / 5;
            int gg = g * 255 / 5;
            int bb = b * 255 / 5;

            colors[index++] = rr << 16 | gg << 8 | b;
        }
    }
}
```

...

```
public static int getColor(int color1, int color2, int color3, int color4){
    return(get(color4) << 24 + get(color3) << 16 + get(color2) << 8 + get(color1));
}

private static int get(int color){
    if(color < 0) return 255;
    int r = color / 100 % 10;
    int g = color / 10 % 10;
    int b = color / 1 % 10;

    return r * 36 + g * 6 + b;
}
```

I'am trying to solve what's happening in here. But i couldnt figure it out. Can someone explain me ?

Answer (score 0):

The first 2 bits of code seems to use an array to store colours as base `256` numbers, but only allowing rgb components that are multiples of `51`. The array is not used in the rest of the code.

The `get` method seems to convert a colour given as a 3-digit base `10` number to a base `6` number.

The third block of code seems to take four colours (given as 3-digit base `10` numbers), convert them into base `6` (for some reason) and pack them into a single `int`.

The first half of code does not seem to relate to the second half.